# Notification in Android Wear - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-intent

I tried below Android Wear Notification code in Android Studio. But, I am not getting any Notification message to my Android Wear.Please can you tell me what is missing in my code that is preventing showing the Notification on my Android Wear.
    **

```
 - beepnotification.java

**package org.heaven.test;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class beepNotification extends Activity {
private TextView mTextView;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_beep_notification);
        final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
        int notificationId = 001;
        int eventId = 1;
        boolean EXTRA_EVENT_ID = true;
// Build intent for notification content
        Intent viewIntent = new Intent(beepNotification.this, test.class);
      viewIntent.putExtra(String.valueOf(EXTRA_EVENT_ID),eventId );
        PendingIntent viewPendingIntent =
         PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, viewIntent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("hello")
                        .setContentText("Beep-Beep Fun Time!")
                        .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent);
// Get an instance of the NotificationManager service
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
                NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
// Build the notification and issues it with notification manager.
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
// Build the notification and issues it with notification manager.
       // notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
                mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
            }
        });
    }
}

**

 - Manifest file

**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.heaven.test" >
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
<activity
            android:name=".test"
            android:allowEmbedded="true"
            android:label="test" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
 <activity
            android:name=".beepNotification"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_beep_notification" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

**

 - gradle.build( wear's gradle file)

**
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:5.0.77'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
}

**

 - rect_activity_beep_notification

**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="org.heaven.test.beepNotification"
    tools:deviceIds="wear_square">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_square" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So you're in a full screen activity in your Wear app and you are posting a notification and you're not seeing the notification after you exit your full screen activity? What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Have you tried to run it in android wear emulator.

Comment: Yes Kishan, I run the android wear emulator and the notification dont show up, only activity screen is seen and is static.